# Laravel perdí configuración Storage::url

Tags: imagen, laravel-blade, laravel-8

Perdí un proyecto por un problema en mi PC. Al descargar de Github el proyecto tuve que re configurar todo pero no lo logro recuperar la funcionalidad para las imágenes. Las imágenes las tenía resguardadas por lo que copie las mismas a la carpeta Storage y no funcionan.
**De hecho si cargo nuevas imágenes tampoco funciona.**

Error:

Imágenes vacías

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al verificar las URL en el inspector de elementos veo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura de carpetas:

MiSitio/storage/...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En las vistas las imágenes las muestro de la siguiente forma:

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url($image->url) }}" />
```

Volví a ejecutar el comando:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Y no resolvió mi problema.

Si accedo a la url de cualquier imagen del sistema me indica:
404 not found

y la url: **http://localhost:8000/storage/posts/7Vl8bNpHp7emLKxUl52S90rOIAlSa62uP1r5aC1U.png**

Si busco en la carpeta storage de imágenes la encuentro en la siguiente dirección:

MiSitio\storage\app\public\posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Es posible que la ruta del `storage` esté mal configurada

Intenta lo siguiente:

1. Abre `config/filesystems.php`
2. Modifica la parte que dice `public` de la siguiente manera:

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path(),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ]
```

3. Borra el folder `storage` de tu carpeta `public` si ya existe
4. Ejecuta `php artisan storage:link`

Si no funciona intenta nuevamente pero en el paso 2 donde dice `'root'` pon lo siguiente  `'root' => storage_path('app/public')`

Comment: Que genio muchas gracias! la primera opción funcionó!!